# Object in Thread sleeps but then awakes in another position

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I have a Thread updating the graphics of the JFrame, and when I put the Thread to sleep the object that I'm using sleeps but when it wakes up it's not in the same position as it was before when it stopped. How can I stop that?

[Theres a gif with the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb1qv.gif)

```
public class Handler {

LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

public void tick() throws InterruptedException{
    for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

        tempObject.tick();

        if (tempObject.x == 100){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

        tempObject.render(g);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the thread is responsible for updating `x` on the object(s). Presumably you have something else that updates `x` -- you need to tell that other thing when it should stop those updates and restart them.

Comment: what happens inside `tempObject.tick`?

Comment: @luk2302 it uses a abstract method from other class (GameObject), that overrides on Handler.